# qTip2 (tooltip) line break not working

Tags: jquery, line-breaks, qtip2

I'm trying to add some line break to the text of the plugin qTip2 without any success.

So far I've tried `<br/>`, `<p>` and also `white-space: pre-line` without any success.

You can view a full example http://jsfiddle.net/6asMt/1/

I've been searching around the  google but can't find anything that works.
I would like my final result to be:

```
Date Start: 2014-04-08 10:00:00
Date End: 2014-04-10-10-00-00
```

And not

```
Date Start: 2014-04-08 10:00:00 Date End: 
2014-04-10-10-00-00
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check this [JS Fiddle Code](http://jsfiddle.net/devangkantharia/8LFfL/)

> JS Code:

```
$('a').each(function () {
    if ($(this).hasClass('qTip')) {
        var value = $(this).next('div:hidden').text();
        var title = $(this).attr('title');
        $('.qTip').qtip({
            style: {
                classes: 'qtip-bootstrap'
            },
            content: {
                title: title,
                //text: value // The problem is here (on the `text` option)
                text: $(this).next('div')[0].innerHTML
            }
        });
    }
});
```

If you have any other issue, then please add a comment below.

Regards D.

Comment: Hi, first of all thanks. I actually have another problem, but I don't know if I need to create another topic for that. Even if the dates are different, the tooltip will always show the last one. http://jsfiddle.net/8LFfL/1/

Answer (score 3):

Just use `html()` instead of `text()` in your code used to get tooltip value.

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/6asMt/8/)

Answer (score 3):

For anyone else that want the newline for the qtip, you can also use this:

```
<br/>
```

in your text.
for example, you set the string that you want to display as below

```
$temp = "date begin: 1/8/2018<br/>date end: 2/8/2019";
```

The rest is still the same. qtip will recognize it and make a new line for it.