# qTip2 loop working but the data information does not change

Tags: jquery, qtip2

A few minutes ago I've created a similiar topic as you can see here:
[qTip2 (tooltip) line break not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25117351/qtip2-tooltip-line-break-not-working/) which is solved.

But my problem now is another.

Here's an example in http://jsfiddle.net/8LFfL/2/.

If you mousehover the links they all have the same `title` and the same `text`, which is incorrect.
If for example I debug the `title` by using `console.log(title)` the value returned is correct for each item in the loop.

What can be wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your old JS:

```
$('a').each(function () {
    if ($(this).hasClass('qTip')) {
        var value = $(this).next('div')[0].innerHTML;
        var title = $(this).attr('title');
        $('.qTip').qtip({
            style: {
                classes: 'qtip-bootstrap'
            },
            content: {
                title: title,
                //text: value // The problem is here (on the `text` option)
                text: value
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Working JS:

```
$('a').each(function () {
    if ($(this).hasClass('qTip')) {
        var value = $(this).next('div')[0].innerHTML;
        var title = $(this).attr('title');
        $(this).qtip({
            style: {
                classes: 'qtip-bootstrap'
            },
            content: {
                title: title,
                //text: value // The problem is here (on the `text` option)
                text: value
            }
        });
    }
});
```

The 5th line is the one that needs changing. `$('.qTip')` selects every single element with that class, and gives them all same values. What you need is to call the `qtip` on `$(this)`, the current `<a>`.

Answer (score 0):

I am sending you [JS Fiddle Code](http://jsfiddle.net/devangkantharia/4TM3K/) here.

Lots of changes are made here in the layout for achieving the proper requirement.

> HTML Code:

```
<div id="inner-dataContainer">
    <div id="tooltipsWrapper">
        <a class="qTip" title="Experience 1" data="text1"> (Experience 1) </a> <a class="qTip" title="Experience 2" data="text2"> (Experience 2) </a> <a class="qTip" title="Testing a little" data="text3"> (Experience 3) </a>
    </div>
</div>
<ul class="popupContent hide">
    <li id="text1" class="popupText">Date Start: 2014-04-08 10:00:00 Date End: 2014-04-10 15-00-00</li>
    <li id="text2" class="popupText">
        <p>Date Start: 2014-04-08 10:00:00</p>
        <p>Date End: 2014-04-10 13-00-00</p>
    </li>
    <li id="text3" class="popupText">
        <p>Date Start: 2014-04-08 10:00:00</p>
        <p>Date End: 2014-04-10 12-00-00</p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

> JS Code:

```
$('#tooltipsWrapper a').each(function () {
        var dataValue = $(this).attr("data");
        aaa = $(".popupContent").find("li#" + dataValue).text();
        $(this).qtip({
            content: {
                text: aaa
            },
            position: {
                target: 'mouse', // Position it where the click was...
                adjust: {
                    scroll: true,
                    method: 'shift none'
                },
                viewport: $("#inner-dataContainer"),
                my: 'top center'
                /*,
                            at: 'bottom left'*/
            },
            style: {
                classes: 'qtip-cream qtip-rounded qtip-shadow custom-styling',
                width: '170px'
            },
            hide: {
                distance: 10
            }
        });
    });
```

> CSS Code:

```
.hide {
    display: none;
}
```

If you have any other issue, then please add a comment below.

Regards D.